# Variance of a Probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to find the variance of the following random variable with density function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x(1+x),& \text{ $|x|\leq1$ }  \\ 
 0& \text{  }  o. w
\end{cases}$$ First, we find $\displaystyle E(x)=\frac{3}{2} \int_{-1}^{1}x^2(1+x)dx=1$ and $E(x^2)= \displaystyle \frac{3}{2} \int_{-1}^{1}x^3(1+x)dx= \frac{3}{5}.$ Now, variance of the random variable $x$ is defined  by $V(x)=E(x^2)-(E(x))^2= \frac{3}{5}-1\Rightarrow \frac{-2}{5}<0$. But, variance can't be negative. Where did I made a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mistake in the question.

When $x=-0.5$, $f(x) < 0$ and $f$ is continuous in that neighborhood, it can't be a pdf.

Comment: Indeed, the function maps to negative values for any $x$ between $-1$ and $0$.